# what is the order of execution of the following C# code?

Tags: c#, object, methods, stringbuilder

In the following code I change a StringBuilder object contect in two diffrent ways .
Does the Shorter code calls and execute the StringBuilder methods in the same order ?

```
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StringBuilder firstString = new StringBuilder("This is a string");
            StringBuilder secondString = new StringBuilder("content");

            /*Long way*/
            Console.WriteLine("Clearing firstString ...and appending diffrent text \nLong code :");
            firstString.Length = 0;
            firstString.Append("This is the same object " + "with a diffrent ");
            firstString.Append(secondString);
            Console.WriteLine($"String is: {firstString} ");

            /*Short way*/
            Console.WriteLine("Clearing firstString ...and appending the same text \nShort code :");
            firstString.Clear().Append("This is the same object " + "with a diffrent ").Append(secondString);
            Console.WriteLine($"String is: {firstString} ");


            Console.Read();
        }
```

Comment: Order of execution in imperative code is as you wrote it. No matter what. It will execute in the order you wrote it. As per the ["Method Cascading"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_cascading) it is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: `Does the Shorter code calls and execute the StringBuilder methods in the same order ?` have you tested this? If not, it's relatively trivial to confirm this. What is your end goal here?

Answer (score 1):

The result is the same.

Since `.Clear()` and `.Append()` [return the `StringBuilder` object for convenience of use as described in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-6.0#calling-stringbuilder-methods),

```
firstString.Clear().Append("This is the same object " + "with a diffrent ").Append(secondString);
```

is equivalent to

```
firstString.Clear();
firstString.Append("This is the same object " + "with a diffrent ");
firstString.Append(secondString);
```